# Visual Studios 2017 - Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<>'

Tags: c#, asp.net, list

I'm just not familiar enough yet to know exactly why this is happening.  Not sure what I'm missing.  I could use some help since the tutorial I was using didn't seem to run up against the same problem...

```
public class CustomerRepository
{
    public List<Customers> GetCustomers()
    {
        var db = new e21testEntities();
        var Customers = db.orderfrom
            .OrderBy(x => x.bus_name)
                .ToList();

        return Customers;
    }
}
```

Customers won't return with an error of

> Cannot implicitly convert type
>   `System.Collections.Generic.List<NestedGrid.orderfrom>` to
>   `System.Collections.Generic.List<NestedGrid.Customers>`

Comment: Is Customers also the name of one of your classes?

Comment: `db.orderfrom` doesn't sounds like it should be a collection of `Customers` objects...

Comment: Also you should retype your error with the correct part inside the `<>`. You'll want to mark it as code by enclosing it in "``" as well so that it doesn't try to treat the stuff in `<>` as markup.

Comment: orderfrom is the name of a table in e21testEntities model. I'm not sure why the developer named it that, but it does have all the customer records in it.   The whole error is "Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<NestedGrid.orderfrom>' to System.Collections.Generic.List<NestedGrid.Customers>'

Comment: Then *update your question* to show the exact error message.

Comment: @StephenGirt: That error message is pretty clear. your `Customers` var is of type `List<NestedGrid.orderfrom>` whereas your GetCustomers method says it is return `List<Customers>`. You need to either change the return type of your method or convert your `orderfrom` objects to `Customers` objects somehow. We are not in a position to tell you how to do this due to lack of information on what those two objects are and what the relationship between them might be.

Comment: Please post the definitions of the classes.

Comment: That was good enough to get me on the right path.  'Customers' wasn't intended to be a class - Code needed to read 'Public List<orderfrom>'

Answer (score -1):

As I understand, you are trying to extract customer data out of order.

In this case, try to use the following instead

```
var db = new e21testEntities();
var Customers = db.orderfrom
    .OrderBy(x => x.bus_name)
    .Select(o=>new Customer() {Id = o.CustomerId})
    .ToList();
```

In the code above, you need to fill customer object manually based on data in each order you have (in the code I fill Id propperty only).

Comment: If the orders do have a `customerID` I would expect them to link to the customer objects in the database so I wouldn't expect the right solution to be manually creating customer objects.

Comment: This is not always the case. However, if the customer entity exists we should get it from the database instead.

Comment: I also assume there is a mistake in "orderfrom" and we should write "orderform" instead, so we work with the form filled by the client.

Comment: Rather than assuming, how about you wait until the question is clear? And if the error was orderfrom instead orderform, then it would be a different error message.

Comment: The table orderfrom literally has no order information....Its really a customers table, I have no clue why they named it that way.  It is confusing.  It has Cust_code, Bus_name, .... It seems to recognize the model and table just fine as it has no issue with .bus_name in the 'orderBy' statement